# What happens with target_link_libraries(libstatic libfoo libbar)?

Tags: cmake, linker

I am bit confused about linking libraries when our target is a static library.

For instance, for an executable it will help linker resolve undefined symbols. But, incase of a static libraries, why would it link at this stage?

Won't linking be done when I will link `some executable` against `libstatic`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake,

```
target_link_libraries(targetName PUBLIC lib1 lib2)
```

affects to the linker's argument in **two scenarios**:

1. *PRIVATE*: when the linker is called for the for the executable/library, corresponded to the target `targetName`.
2. *INTERFACE*: when the linker is called for the **other** executable/library `otherTargetName`, which is linked with `targetName` via

   ```
   target_link_libraries(otherTargetName PUBLIC targetName)
   ```

   This is known as **transitive** property of the linking libraries.

You are right that the linker is not called for the *static* libraries, so in that case the first scenario is eliminated.

But the second scenario remains: When you create the executable (or other shared library) and call

```
target_link_libraries(otherTargetName PUBLIC libStatic)
```

then CMake **automatically** links that executable(or shared library) with everything, to which `libStatic` is "linked" with `target_link_libraries`.

---

Such automation helps in structuring the project:

1. By calling

   ```
   target_link_libraries(libStatic PUBLIC lib1 lib2)
   ```

   you state, that `libStatic` uses functions defined in `lib1` and `lib2`
2. By calling

   ```
   target_link_libraries(otherTargetName PUBLIC libStatic)
   ```

   you state, that executable/library `otherTargetName` uses functions from `libStatic`.

   At this stage you **don't care about internals** of `libStatic`, whether it is self-contained or depends from some other libraries: CMake will care about this for you.

---

Note on using `PUBLIC` keyword in `target_link_libraries`: while in some cases this is equivalent to omitting the keyword, a modern CMake way is to specify keywords **explicitly**. See also [policy CMP0023](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/policy/CMP0023.html).

Other possible keywords are `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE`, each of them selects only a single scenario described above.

---

Note that transitive linking property is a pure CMake feature and works only when linking to a **target**. The library file (`.a` or `.lib`) itself doesn't contain information about dependent libraries, so linking with a *file* doesn't trigger transitive linking.